# How to evaluate double integral of non-elementary functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate this double integral
$$\int_{0}^1\int_{x^2}^x \frac{x}{y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{y}}dydx.$$

It seems like I am evaluating the double integral of a non-elementary function. I tried substitutions but the integral is growing.

---

Following Fred's suggestion, the integral evaluates to $\frac{e-2}{2e}$

Comment: The usual approach to textbook exercises of the genre "evaluate this double integral" is to reverse the order of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\int_{0}^1\int_{x^2}^x \frac{x}{y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{y}}dydx=\int_{0}^1\int_{y}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{x}{y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{y}}dxdy.$

Answer (score 2):

Let's first sketch out the bounds of integration. These are

- $x=0$
- $x=1$
- $y=x$
- $y=x^2$

Doing so and noting the order of the bounds, we realize we're integrating over the region in green:

[image]

Let's reverse the order of integration. We were going $y$ and then $x$, so go for $x$ then $y$.

With this in mind, and using the sketch above, we go from $y=x$ to $y = x^2$ in the $x$ direction. Equivalently, $x=y$ to $x = \sqrt y$. The relevant $y$ bounds are clearly $0$ to $1$ by similar reasoning. Therefore, your integral is equivalent to

$$\int_0^1 \int_y^{\sqrt y} \frac x y e^{x^2/y} \; dx \; dy$$

From here, solving the inner integral now seems like a much more feasible exercise. Begin with a $u$-substitution of $u=x^2/y$, and thus

$$du = \frac{2x}{y} \cdot dx \implies dx = \frac{y}{2x} \cdot du$$

It should be pretty easy to proceed from here; I'll leave the remainder to you.